# Type of a double

Tags: haskell

Learning Haskell, in `ghci`:

```
Prelude Data.Ratio> :type 0.15
0.15 :: Fractional a => a

Prelude Data.Ratio> 0.15
0.15
it :: Double
```

Why are types different? Are those two instances of 0.15 actually different types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the monomorphism restriction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This due to the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction).  Basically, GHCi likes to choose default types when executed (the default `Fractional` type is `Double`), but when you ask the type using `:type` it chooses the most general version.  You can disable this behavior with the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` extension:

```
> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
> :set +t
> 0.15
0.15
it :: Fractional a => a
> :t 0.15
0.15 :: Fractional a => a
```

While this this extension has one of the scarier names, it's rather simple when you break it down:

```
Mono  -> One
Morph -> shape (type)
ism   -> thingy
Monomorphism -> one shape thingy -> one type thingy -> thing with a single type
```

So basically it's a really long word that means "single type".  Then with "restriction", you get that the monomorphism restriction is restricting things to a single type.  In this case, it's restricting numbers (the things) to the type `Double`.  Without this restriction, the type of the numbers is only constrained by a type class, which can in theory be an infinite number of types.

Comment: I note that even though it displays `it :: Fractional a => a`, it obviously needs to choose *some* type for evaluating and printing the actual result "`0.15`" (e.g. `0.15 :: Rational` is printed differently), so there is *some* defaulting and `Double` involved even with `NoMonomorphismRestriction`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: that's a good point, although I'd guess that `:type` simply echos the entered string, in which case no defaulting is necessary.

Comment: @JohnL Yes, I was referring to the two-line response to the `> 0.15` line in this answer.