# Error while compiling print Either value

Tags: haskell, either

I'm trying to compile simple code snippet.

```
main = (putStrLn . show) (Right 3.423)
```

Compile results in the following error:

```
No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `show'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Show Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  ...plus 42 others
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `show'
In the expression: putStrLn . show
In the expression: (putStrLn . show) (Right 3.423)
```

When i execute same snippet from ghci everything works as expected.

```
Prelude> let main = (putStrLn . show) (Right 3.423)
Prelude> main
Right 3.423
```

So the question is what is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>The problem is that GHC can't determine what the full type of `Right 3.423` is, it can only determine that it has the type `Either a Double`, and the instance of `Show` for `Either` looks like `instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Either a b)`.  Without that extra constraint on `Either a Double`, GHC doesn't know how to print it.</strike>

The reason why it works in interactive mode is because of the [dreaded](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) monomorphism [restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942957/type-of-a-double/23942989#23942989), which makes GHCi more aggressive in the defaults it chooses.  This can be disabled with `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`, and that is going to become the default in future versions of GHC since it causes a lot of problems for beginners.

The solution to this problem is to put a type signature on `Right 3.423` in your source code, like

```
main = (putStrLn . show) (Right 3.423 :: Either () Double)
```

Here I've just used `()` for `a`, since we don't care about it anyway and it's the "simplest" type that can be shown.  You could put `String` or `Int` or `Double` or whatever you want there, so long as it implements `Show`.

A tip, `putStrLn . show` is exactly the definition of `print`, so you can just do

```
main = print (Right 3.423 :: Either () Double)
```

---

As @ØrjanJohansen points out, this is not the monomorphism restriction, but rather the `ExtendedDefaultRules` extension that GHCi uses, which essentially does exactly what I did above and shoves `()` into type variables to make things work in the interactive session.

Comment: Actually, `Data.Void.Void` is the simplest type in `Show`, although it can't actually be shown successfully.

Comment: @dfeuer Technically true, but `()` is a pretty simple choice to go with still.  I figure it's an easier explanation that `()` can often be used to fill in type variables that don't really matter, but need to be concrete in order to satisfy a typeclass instance like `Show`.  This obviously doesn't work for all situations, but it works pretty well for a lot of them.

Comment: This is not the monomorphism restriction, which is *always* on by default for file modules.  It is because of GHCi's `ExtendedDefaultRules`, which allow it to choose a default (in fact the same `()` that you chose) even when only a `Show` instance is required (normally the restrictions include that at least one numerical class is needed.)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen My mistake, I'll update my answer.  I know I've seen the `ExtendedDefaultRules` before, but my first thought when I see a problem like this is the monomorphism restriction, and I probably just jumped the gun on answering the question instead of thinking about it for a few more minutes.

Comment: I don't think you need to strike out more than your second paragraph though, the rest is useful and applies to this case as well.