# Does flip alter the parameter data types of functions

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

It seems like flip is doing unexpected things to my functions

Example 1:

```
let m = flip max
:t max
max :: Ord a => a -> a ->
:t m
m :: () -> () -> ()
```

Example 2:

```
let f x y = x + y
:t f
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
let g = flip f
:t g
g :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

`f` can evaluate floating point numbers, but `g` throws an error when it sees floats.  But when I run

```
(flip f) 1.5 1.7
```

This evaluates fine! 
What is the difference between these expressions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The dreaded monomorphism restriction strikes again!](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)

This is due to the monomorphism restriction, which causes polymorphic functions to be restricted to a monomorphic type in GHCi.  Just run `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` or give `m` an explicit type signature to get around this (hint: `:set +m` enables multiline mode in GHCi).

---

See these questions for explanations:

- [Why do 3 and x (which was assigned 3) have different inferred types in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7055146/839246)
- [Type of a double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23942957/839246)